# Update table from another table in SQL is giving an unexpected result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

Table `Items` : 

**ItemCode---Name-------Stock**

111-----------Book---------10

112-----------Bag-----------03

113-----------Pen-----------08

114-----------Pencil--------13

Table `INVOICEITEMS(SoldItems)` : 

**BillNumber---ItemCode-----UnitValue(Qty)**

1005-----------111------------------3

1005-----------111------------------2

1005-----------113------------------4

1006-----------111------------------6

1007-----------112------------------5

We need to update the `ITEMS` table from `INVOICEITEMS` table.

We need to add to the Stock of each ItemCode in ITEMS table from the sum of the UnitValues of 
BillNumber '1005' in INVOICEITEMS.


Query used :

`UPDATE ITEMS SET Stock=Stock+(SELECT SUM(T.UnitValue) FROM INVOICEITEMS T WHERE T.BillNumber LIKE '1005' AND T.ItemCode LIKE ItemCode) WHERE ItemCode IN(SELECT J.ItemCode FROM INVOICEITEMS J WHERE J.BillNumber LIKE '1005')`

Expected Result After updation : 

Table ITEMS

**ItemCode---Name----Stock**

111-----------Book-------15

112-----------Bag---------03

113-----------Pen---------12

114-----------Pencil------13


Result we are getting:

Table ITEMS

**ItemCode---Name----Stock**

111-----------Book--------19

112-----------Bag---------03

113-----------Pen---------17

114-----------Pencil-------13

Please help in correcting this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to investigate problems with update statements is to convert them to select statements. For your update statement, I come up with the following query:

```
SELECT Items.*
   ,(SELECT SUM(T.UnitValue) FROM INVOICEITEMS T WHERE T.BillNumber LIKE '1005' AND T.ItemCode LIKE ItemCode)
FROM Items
WHERE ItemCode IN(SELECT J.ItemCode FROM INVOICEITEMS J WHERE J.BillNumber LIKE '1005')
```

As you can see, the last column is 9 for every row, which isn't surprising because you have not done anything to return different values based on which row you're looking at.
You can then change the select statement to return the data you do want:

```
SELECT Items.ItemCode
   ,Items.Stock
   ,SUM(T.UnitValue)
   ,Items.Stock + SUM(T.UnitValue)
FROM Items
JOIN INVOICEITEMS T ON T.ItemCode = Items.ItemCode
WHERE T.BillNumber = 1005
GROUP BY Items.ItemCode, Items.Stock
```

And finally you can incorporate that back into an UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE Items SET Stock = NewSum
FROM Items JOIN
   (SELECT Items.ItemCode
      ,Items.Stock
      ,Items.Stock + SUM(INVOICEITEMS.UnitValue) NewSum
   FROM Items
   JOIN INVOICEITEMS ON INVOICEITEMS.ItemCode = Items.ItemCode
   WHERE INVOICEITEMS.BillNumber = 1005
   GROUP BY Items.ItemCode, Items.Stock
   ) T ON T.ItemCode = Items.ItemCode
```

It might then be prudent to extract hard-coded values from the sub-query and make them part of the higher-level query. One reason this might be a good idea is because then the sub-query is more portable. Then you'd end up with this:

```
UPDATE Items SET Stock = NewSum
FROM Items JOIN
   (SELECT Items.ItemCode
      ,INVOICEITEMS.BillNumber
      ,Items.Stock
      ,SUM(INVOICEITEMS.UnitValue) InvoiceQty
      ,Items.Stock + SUM(INVOICEITEMS.UnitValue) NewSum
   FROM Items
   JOIN INVOICEITEMS ON INVOICEITEMS.ItemCode = Items.ItemCode
   GROUP BY Items.ItemCode, Items.Stock, INVOICEITEMS.BillNumber
   ) T ON T.ItemCode = Items.ItemCode
WHERE T.BillNumber = 1005
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning converting to SELECT statement in order to see what the query it doing!  Many people don't think of that and it is an easy troubleshooting tip!!

Answer (score 1):

`AND T.ItemCode LIKE ItemCode` line in the SQL is not getting executed as `ItemCode` hasn't been specified in the SQL before the execution of the inner SQL statement.

Associate `ItemCode` explicitly with  the `ITEMS` table and it would work.

Comment: the query mentioned by @5uperdan should work. let us know if you face any issues with that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this case you could use a Stored Procedure or a Function:

e.g. Define a Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION getItemSum(@BillID int, @ItemID int)
RETURNS int 
AS 
-- Returns the stock level for the product.
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ret int;
    SELECT @ret = SUM(UnitValue) 
    FROM INVOICEITEM p 
    WHERE p.ITEMCODE = @ItemID 
        AND p.BillNumber = @BillID;
     IF (@ret IS NULL) 
        SET @ret = 0;
    RETURN @ret;
END;
GO
```

And Call SQL Statement like this:

```
UPDATE ITEMS 
SET Stock=Stock + getItemSum(1005, ItemCode)
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use a join with a sub-query:

```
UPDATE items
SET Stock += item_qty_sum
FROM items i
INNER JOIN (
          SELECT itemcode, SUM(unitvalue) AS item_qty_sum 
          FROM INVOICEITEMS 
          WHERE BillNumber = 1005 
          GROUP BY ItemCode
          ) ii
ON ii.ItemCode = i.ItemCode
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/da53d/1) showing the query in action giving the desired results.